For $\pi : M \to N$ a submersion, then $ \mathcal{F}_{\pi} := \ker d\pi = \{ X \in TM : d\pi(X) = 0 \} $ is an involutive distribution on $M$
If $\pi : M \to N$ is a submersion, then $ \mathcal{F}_{\pi} := \ker d\pi = \{ X \in TM : d\pi(X) = 0 \} $ is an involutive distribution on $M$.
I was presented with this example when I was introduced to distributions, which makes use of the:
Theorem(Frobenius): A distribution $\mathcal{F}$ on a manifold $M$ is integrable iff it is involutive.
However I was told be it can also be proven without it, how would you do that?
I have the following:
Def Given a distribution $\mathcal{F}$ on $M$, we say that $\mathcal{F}$ is involutive if:
$[X, Y] \in \Gamma(\mathcal{F}) \quad \forall \, X, Y \in \Gamma(\mathcal{F}).$
Def A p-dimensional distribution on a manifold $M$ is a rank $p$ vector sub-bundle of the tangent bundle, $\mathcal{F} \subset TM.$

The difficult implication in the Frobenius theorem is "involutive implies integrable"; the other one is clear since the Lie bracket between vector fields tangent to a submanifold is also tangent to the submanifold. For every $x\in M$, the fiber $\pi^{-1}(\pi(x))$ is an integral submanifold of $\ker {\rm d}\pi$ passing through $x$ (they are submanifolds because $\pi$ is a submersion). So $\ker {\rm d}\pi$ is integrable, and by the easy implication of Frobenius, involutive.

@IvoTerek The question was how to prove ker $d\pi $ is involutive without using the Frobenius theorem

Ok, you don't want to use even the easy implication in Frobenius. I have posted an answer below just relying on the local form of submersions.

Since $\pi$ is a submersion, we may find coordinates $(x^1,\ldots, x^{n+k})$ on $M$ and $(x^1,\ldots, x^n)$ on $N$ on which $\pi$ appears as the projection $(x^1,\ldots, x^{n+k}) \mapsto (x^1,\ldots, x^n)$. This means that the level sets of $\pi$ are described as
$$x^1 = c^1,\qquad \ldots\qquad x^n=c^n,$$for constants $c^1,\ldots, c^n\in \mathbb{R}$. Involutivity is a local condition, and note that
$$\sum_{i=1}^n X^i\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} + \sum_{i=n+1}^{n+k} X^i\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} \in \ker {\rm d}\pi \iff X^1=\cdots=X^n = 0.$$
Now assume that $X$ and $Y$ are tangent to $\ker {\rm d}\pi$, and written as
$$X = \sum_{i=n+1}^{n+k} X^i\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\quad\mbox{and}\quad Y = \sum_{i=n+1}^{n+k} Y^i\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}.$$Then $$[X,Y] = \sum_{i=n+1}^{n+k}  (X(Y^i) - Y(X^i))\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} \in \ker {\rm d}\pi,$$as wanted.

Looks like I mixed up the terminology, what I really wanted to ask is to proved that $ker d\pi $is integrable, knowing already that it is involutive and withouth using the Frobenious theorem.

I opened a new question, if you have time take a look https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4985724/for-pi-m-to-n-a-submersion-then-ker-d-pi-x-in-tm-d-pix-0

Then my very first comment in the post did what you wanted: integrable means that through every point you can find an integral submanifold passing through that point. This is the definition of integrable. Given $x\in M$, here is an integral submanifold of $\ker {\rm d}\pi$ passing through $x$: $\pi^{-1}(\pi(x))$.
