For $\pi : M \to N$ a submersion, then $ \ker d\pi = \{ X \in TM : d\pi(X) = 0 \} $ is integrable on $M$
If $\pi : M \to N$ is a submersion, then one can show that
$ \mathcal{F}_{\pi} := \ker d\pi = \{ X \in TM : d\pi(X) = 0 \} $ is an involutive distribution on $M$.
Then one can conclude that it is integrable using the:
Theorem(Frobenius): A distribution $\mathcal{F}$ on a manifold $M$ is integrable iff it is involutive.
However I was told that using Frobenius is too much technology and that it can be proven without it. How do you do that? I mean assuming we already know $ker d\pi$ involutive, deduce that it is integrable without Frobenius.
I have the following definitions:
Def Given a distribution $\mathcal{F}$ on $M$, we say that $\mathcal{F}$ is involutive if:
$[X, Y] \in \Gamma(\mathcal{F}) \quad \forall \, X, Y \in \Gamma(\mathcal{F}).$
Def A p-dimensional distribution on a manifold $M$ is a rank $p$ vector sub-bundle of the tangent bundle, $\mathcal{F} \subset TM.$
Def An $\textit{integral}$ of $\mathcal{F}$ is any immersed connected submanifold $N \hookrightarrow M$ with the property that
$$
T_p N = \mathcal{F}_p \quad \forall \, p \in N.
$$
$\mathcal{F}$ is $\textit{integrable}$ if for any $p \in M$ there exists such an integral with $p \in N$. We also say that $\mathcal{F}$ defines a $\textit{foliation}$ on $M$, or that $(M, \mathcal{F})$ is a $\textit{foliated manifold}.$

The answer you accepted to your earlier question answers this question directly. The local product coordinates give you the integral submanifolds explicitly, locally.
